# Load a page range with kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, kaminari

I need to load a page range with kaminari. What I mean is something like:

Model.page(1..5).per(10)

So I would get the first 50 items at the first page and continue with 10 items per page after that.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got around the same issue by doing something along these lines:

```
if first_load
    ar = []
    (1..n).each do |p|
        ar << Model.page(p)
    end
    ar.flatten 
else
    Model.page(n).per(10)
end
```

Comment: Ah, I am not certain. My use of the gem ironically didn't require use of the pager. Sorry about that.